# Capistrano-Puma Not Starting Puma Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3, puma

## Issue Facing

When I run `bundle exec cap production puma:start`, I get the response that Puma has started successfully:

```
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    * Pruning Bundler environment
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] Puma starting in cluster mode...
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Version 3.0.2 (ruby 2.2.1-p85), codename: Plethora of Penguin Pinatas
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Environment: staging
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Process workers: 2
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Phased restart available
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9294
DEBUG [e4382d1e]
DEBUG [e4382d1e]    [2599] * Daemonizing...
```

However,

1. When I run `bundle exec cap production puma:status`, it says that it cannot find file `puma.pid`, therefore I think that Puma is not running, and *it is not* running,
2. on the server, `curl 0.0.0.0:9294` prints `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9294: Connection refused`,
3. the file `puma.pid` doesn't exist on the server, and
4. if I try to start Puma on the server manually, it works fine.

## My Setup Information

Here's part of my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'puma'

group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
end
```

Here's the `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
```

Here's the `config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
server 'aws', user: 'my-username', roles: %w{app db web}
set :puma_bind, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:9294'
```

Any idea on:

1. What is the cause of issue?
2. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Update: here's the repo with the Capistrano file. I've left with only Capistrano part (it's a fresh new project): https://github.com/flyfy1/CodeRead/

Comment: From the output, it looks like puma did start. Are there puma logs that might tell you why it probably died right after?

Comment: @will_in_wi I didn't find any Puma Log.. but I've added the link to the Capistrano project

Comment: I found the puma logs in `shared/logs/puma.access.log` and `puma.error.log`.

Answer (score 11):

I just meet the same problem, and fixed it. When you use cap puma:start, you will see the following sentences in terminal:

```
 puma:start
      using conf file /your_web_app_path/shared/puma.rb
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /your_web_app_path/shared/puma.rb --daemon
```

execute `bundle exec puma -C /your_web_app_path/shared/puma.rb` at your_web_app_path/current/, without the deamon option.

And it will tell you what's wrong with you application. For me, it told me that

```
 No such file or directory @ rb_io_reopen - /my_web_app_path/shared/log/puma_access.log
```

Comment: Great answer! Shows how to find the cause of the issue

Comment: This tells you what's wrong, but not how to fix it.... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Erick Maynard In my problem, just simply create a file: /my_web_app_path/shared/log/puma_access.log

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Capistrano-Puma expects specific [shared directories](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/) otherwise the server won't start.

These are:
  [tmp/pids](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma#config)
  [tmp/sockets log](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma#config)

#### Solution

Create shared directories in deploy.rb with:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w(tmp/pids tmp/sockets log)
```

#### Verification**

cap puma:start says it is started but doesn't tell you it then fails. Verify with:

```
cap puma:status
```

or

```
ps -ax | grep puma
```